# establish communication between metro and desktop

Tags: dll, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to make my store app communication with desktop app through websockets. 
I know we can make metro app as a client and do WinRT way of communicating over.
For the desktop server part, i'm planning to write a dll that will contain server code and receive metro texts being sent over.

**Can someone please tell if this is possible  and how to write server code in a dll and if so should we be using winhttp for wbesockets in server side ?**

Answer (score 0):

Windows Store (WInRT) apps are executing in a sandbox which isolates them from network communication with other applications on the local machine (`localhost`). That being said, this protection can be disabled using [`CheckNetIsolation.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780593.aspx). Visual Studio automatically does the same for debugging purposes, allowing you to call e.g. a web service on your local machine during development.

As for the desktop side; to communicate with web sockets client, you can make advantage of WinHTTP. There's a working example on [MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WinHTTP-WebSocket-sample-50a140b5).

Keep in mind, though, that any application communicating with `localhost` will not be certified for Windows Store and will require several additional steps to install it:

- The Windows Store application package will need to be sideloaded since it won't be published in Windows Store.
- Any desktop component it communicates with will need to be installed separately the same way as any other desktop application.
- Using `CheckNetIsolation.exe` loopback exemption will need to be added for the Windows Store app.

If you can avoid it, I definitely suggest you don't try communicating directly with a desktop application from you Windows Store app.

Comment: Thanks so much. Yeah I went through the sample you'd mentioned. I want to write a Winhttp websocket server instead of client..can you please help me with that ?

Comment: @minu There's a server component in the above sample as well, but it's implemented as an `IHttpHandler` and hosted in IIS. If you need a self hosted solution, take a look at a third party library, such as [Alchemy Websockets](http://alchemywebsockets.net/).

Comment: Again thanks a lot for the directions. I wanted to create one in C++ specially for websockets. I saw there were API's for Winhttp client but couldnt find one for server.